# Commands run in a batch file only when writing cmd /c before

Tags: batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

I am running the following command

```
rabbitmq-server.bat" -detached
```

This command runs a sewrver in the background. 
When I run it from a batch files - the flow stops and later commands in the batch stop running .

1. Why?
2. What is the best way to run those kind of commands?
3. Running them with cmd /c does the job but I not for all of those commands

Answer (score 1):

This is daft behaviour that Microsoft's CMD retains for backwards compatibility all of the way back to the earliest versions of Microsoft's COMMAND.  If one command script runs another command script, the first command script is cancelled.

The way to get around this is with the `call` built-in command.  Simply prefix the command script with `call`.  This yields the behaviour that you, and I suspect most people, expect: the calling command script resumes execution when the called command script terminates.

You can also use `cmd /c`, but note that that's not the same thing.  `call` just nests command scripts within the same command interpreter.  `cmd /c` starts up an additional new command interpreter sub-process.  Changes made to variables, the working directory, open file handles, and suchlike in the sub-process won't affect its parent.  Conversely, `call` is portable, should one be using replacement command interpreters, whereas `cmd` ties one to a specific command interpreter.

### Further reading

- JP Software. [*CALL*](http://jpsoft.com/help/call.htm).  Take Command / TCC Help.
- [*"CALL"*](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb490873.aspx).  *Windows XP Command-line reference A–Z.*  TechNet.  Microsoft corporation.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a case for using "Start.exe"

**Start will allow you to start the server process in a separate window and leave it running.**

The original batch script will then continue executing the commands in the script without waiting for the server process to end.

While those commands do not affect that separately running process, however as is likely the case you can use some commands that are intended to interact with the running Rabit MQ Server in the following portion of the batch script and they will function correctly.

So long as you put in a pause of sufficient length from the time the START command is executed to the time the client commands are initiated to give the rabbit server enough time to fully instantiate. (This could be done with a pause which you manually press enter to continue or a ping to have a timer.)

**Using "CALL" or "CMD /C" without "Start" will have the batch script wait until you end the execution of the RabitMQ server command before continuing.**